# TypeORM: Insert an entity which has many to many relation with another entity (based on existing records)

Tags: typeorm

I have 2 following entities with Many To Many relationship

- User entity (relationship owned by the User entity)

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToMany, JoinTable, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Role } from './role.schema';

@Entity('Users')
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'Id' })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'Email',
    length: 100,
    unique: true
  })
  email: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'FirstName',
    length: 30
  })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'LastName',
    length: 30
  })
  lastName: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => Role, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'UserRoles',
    joinColumns: [
      { name: 'UserId' }
    ],
    inverseJoinColumns: [
      { name: 'RoleId' }
    ]
  })
  roles: Role[];
}
```

- Role entity (with two existing roles: Admin and User)

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.schema';

@Entity("Roles")
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'Id' })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'Name',
    length: 50,
    unique: true
  })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.roles)
  users: User[];
}
```

the design of application is such that Role name is sent in request in the form of an array e.g. ['Admin', 'User']

Now while inserting a User,
currently I first retrieve Role object from database based on the role name array received in request (to assign a desired role),
then assign it to the User object (roles property) and
then finally call save method on User object to insert the record in User table.

**Snippet:**

```js
createConnection(connectionConfig as ConnectionOptions).then(async connect => {

  let userRepo = connect.getRepository(User);
  let roleRepo = connect.getRepository(Role);
  let roles = ['Admin', 'User'];
  let user = userRepo.create();

  return roleRepo.createQueryBuilder('role').where('role.name IN (:roleNames)', { roleNames: roles }).getMany().then((roles) => {
    user.email = 'test1@test.test';
    user.firstName = 'TestFName';
    user.lastName = 'TestLName';
    user.roles = roles;
    return userRepo.save(user)
  })

}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This results in many database calls. It would be great if some one can enlighten me with smarter and more elegant way ( using fluent QueryBuilder to achieve above result)

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: I think the cascade: true option in the @ManyToMany Attribute is what you are searching for. See https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#cascades

Comment: Am looking for this myself - it seems cascade: true doesn't work with QueryBuilder, only with Save.
Would love any insight on this

Comment: [It could help you. please have a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54886350/9808302)