# How to save relation in @ManyToMany in typeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, nestjs, typeorm

There are 2 entities named `Article` and `Classification`. And the relation of them is `@ManyToMany`.

Here's my question: How to save the relation?

My code as below:

```
  @Entity()
    export class Article {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

        @Column()
        name: string;

        @CreateDateColumn()
        createTime: Date;

        @UpdateDateColumn()
        updateTime: Date;

        @Column({
            type: 'text',
        })
        content: string;

        @Column({
            default: 0,
        })
        likeAmount: number;

        @Column({
            default: 0,
        })
        commentAmount: number;
    }

    @Entity()
    export class Classification {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

        @CreateDateColumn()
        createTime: Date;

        @UpdateDateColumn()
        updateTime: Date;

        @Column()
        name: string;

        @ManyToMany(type => Article)
        @JoinTable()
        articles: Article[];
    }
```

I can save the `Article` and `Classification` successful. But I'm not sure how to save the relation of them.

I have tried to save the relation via below code:

```
async create(dto: ArticleClassificationDto): Promise<any> {
    const article = this.repository.save(dto);
    article.then(value => {
      console.log(value);//console the object article
      value.classification.forEach(item => {
        const classification = new Classification();
        classification.id = item.id;
        classification.articles = [];
        classification.articles.push(value);
        this.classificationService.save(classification);
      })
    });
    console.log(article);
    return null;
  }
```

And the post data strcture like that

```
    {
        "name":"artile name",
        "content":"article content",
        "classification":[{
            "id":4
        },{
            "id":3
        }]
    }
```

At the beginning, it works.

[image]

But when I post the data again, the old record was replaced rather create another record.

[image]

What should I do next?

Just look below code please.

```
async create(dto: ArticleClassificationDto): Promise<any> {
    this.repository.save(dto).then(article => {
      article.classification.forEach(item => {
        this.ClassificationRepository.findOne(
          {
            // the privous method is get all the articles from databse and push into this array
            // relations: ['articles'],
            where: { id: item }// now I change the data strcture, just contains id instead of {id}
          }
        ).then(classification => {
          // console.log(article);
          console.log(classification);
          // cmd will show ' UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' withous below line code. But if I init the array manually,the old record will be replaced again.
          // classification.articles = [];
          classification.articles.push(article);
          this.ClassificationRepository.save(classification);
        });
      })
    })
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### How to save relations?

Let's assume you have an array of articles and you want to create a relation to a classification entity. You just assign the array to the property `articles` and save the entity; typeorm will automatically create the relation.

```
classification.articles = [article1, article2];
await this.classificationRepository.save(classification);
```

For this to work, the article entities have to be saved already. If you want typeorm to automatically save the article entities, you can set [`cascade`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#cascades) to `true`.

```
@ManyToMany(type => Article, article => article.classifications, { cascade: true })
```

---

### Your example

```
async create(dto: ArticleClassificationDto): Promise<any> {
  let article = await this.repository.create(dto);
  article = await this.repository.save(article);
  const classifications = await this.classificationRepository.findByIds(article.classification, {relations: ['articles']});
  for (const classification of classifications) {
    classification.articles.push(article);
  }
  return this.classificationRepository.save(classifications);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method. And it didn't work for me. I have updated my question, can u help next?

Comment: This is a different problem now: You are posting the `classifications` with their `id`'s. `id` is the `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` of the `classification` entity. If you want to create a new object, you must not include the primary column, otherwise the entity will be updated instead of created if the primary column (`id`) already exists.

Comment: But I just wanna save the relation of them. Not save the entity `Classification`.I do wanna create a new object, but not `classification`, just new relation of `classification ` and `article`.And I need the `id` of `Classification` automatically generated with an auto-increment value when I insert a new `Classification`. I'm not clear how to realize my target?

Comment: Ok, so all entities already exist; you just want to create the relation between the entities!? Then just load your classification entity from the database `findOne(classificationId)`, assign the articles to the classification entity you loaded from the database and then save the classification entity.

Comment: I have done as what u said. But there was something wrong with it. I have posted the code in the question.

Comment: You are creating a new entity `const classification = new Classification();` instead of loading the existing one from the database.

Comment: Are you sure the code you watched is below `Just look below code please`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189314/discussion-between-kim-kern-and-eve).

Comment: thx, I have tried to add ManyToMany in Article,Now I have ManyToMany in Article and Classification,but still not work for me. And I tried another solution: find all articles that classification contains, just like `classification{id:4,articles:[article1,article2]}`,then  `classification.articles.push(newArticle)`.Then it works. But I know this is a terrible solution.

Comment: I guess I figure it out. When I create a object of Classification. And set its id. In that time, the articles is empty. So I push one article in it, the typeorm will think it has only one article even if it has a lot of articles in database? So the previous solution is right?

Comment: Mh, I'm afraid I can't completely follow what you're doing. :-/ However, you should *either* create a new entity without setting an `id` or load an existing entity from the database with its `id`.

Comment: emm,sorry to bother u, cause my english is not good. How about chatting in the linking now you posted yesterday?

Answer (score 3):

in my case i have user and role, 1st you have to initialize your manytomany in your entities :

in user entity :

```
@ManyToMany((type) => Role, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    name: "users_roles",
    joinColumn: { name: "userId", referencedColumnName: "id" },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: "roleId" }
  })
  roles: Role[];
```

in role entity :

```
  //Many-to-many relation with user
  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.roles)
  users: User[];
```

in my service i create a new entity from my data then i added role data to my new entity object :

```
let entity = await this.userRepository.create(data);
let entity2 = {
        ...entity,
        roles: data.selectedRoles,
      };
const user = await this.userRepository.save(entity2);
```

this is the exemple in [typeorm](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/saving-many-to-many-relations) website :

```
const category1 = new Category();
category1.name = "animals";
await connection.manager.save(category1);

const category2 = new Category();
category2.name = "zoo";
await connection.manager.save(category2);

const question = new Question();
question.title = "dogs";
question.text = "who let the dogs out?";
question.categories = [category1, category2];
await connection.manager.save(question);
```