# NestJs/TypeORM: How to save Many to Many

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to save a Many to Many relationship. Each entity by itself is working great.

Here are the two entity files I am working with:

```
// location.entity

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.locations, { eager: true, cascade: true })
@JoinTable()
users: User[];
```

```
// user.entity
@ManyToMany(type => Location, location => location.users, { eager: false })
locations: Location[];
```

Here is the user repository:

```
// user.repository
...
user.locations = locations;  // [1,2,3]
user.uuid = uuidv4();

try {
    await user.save();
      
    for (const location of user.locations) {
        locationsArray.push({ locationId: location, userId: user.id });
    }

    await user.locations.save(locationsArray);
```

Looking at [this guide](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations) makes it seem like I should be able to call `save()` on my relationship. In my case `user.locations.save(locations)`.

However, that is returning an error:

> Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Location[]'.

Using [this S.O thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885935/how-to-save-relation-in-manytomany-in-typeorm) I know I need to loop through the array of location Id's and create the actual object I need to save:

```
[{ locationId: location, userId: user.id }]
```

I need to save the user *first* so I can get a userId.

How can I save my relationship to my `location_users_user` table? Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Thank you @Youba! See the solution below for more info.
Hopefully this will help someone else...

```
// location.entity.ts

...

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.locations, { eager: false })
@JoinTable()
users: User[];
```

```
// user.entity.ts

...

@ManyToMany(type => Location, location => location.users, { eager: false, cascade: true })
locations: Location[];
```

`cascade` is false by default. Enabling this will allow you to call the `save` method and the pivot table will update appropriately.

You'll also need to pull in another module (user/locations etc). Thanks to Youba, you can [see how to implement that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780539/nestjs-how-can-i-import-one-repository-into-another/65781724#65781724)

Answer (score 2):

**What** you need to do is to get the locations data and bind it to the new  user

```
...
  
try {
    
 const user = new User(); //user entity
user.uuid = uuidv4();
   const locationsData: Location[] = await this.locationRepository.findByIds(locations); // array of location entity
    await user.locations = locationsData;
   await user.save();
    }
```

Comment: thank you SO much for [both suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780539/nestjs-how-can-i-import-one-repository-into-another/65781724#65781724) I am going to update my question to hopefully help others. Your suggestions were a tremendous help!