# NestJs: How can I import one repository into another?

Tags: nestjs

I apologize for what is likely a very amateur question. Coming from Laravel, this is still quite confusing to me and I just don't understand what is needed.

I have a `user.repository.ts` file and a `location.repository.ts` file. Each have their own modules, controllers and services. I have successfully created CRUD operations for each entity but now am trying to work towards a Many to Many relationship.

In my `user.repository.ts` file, I am trying to save a related (many to many) repository:

```
// user.repository.ts

user.locations = await this.locationRepository.findByIds(locations);
...

await user.save();
```

I am not sure how to inject or import the `location.repository.ts` file. I have tried numerous variations of importing the service into each module. Or importing each module *into* the other module. I have tried different versions of this:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
@EntityRepository(Location)
```

Or importing the `LocationService` into the `UserService`.

In Laravel, this would be as "simple" as `$model->sync($relationship);`

How can I import/inject the `locationRepository` into my `userRepository`? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this question is related to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779400/nestjs-typeorm-how-to-save-many-to-many), the simplest way to implement it, Add `Location`entity to your `UserModule`

```
@Module({
imports:[TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository,LocationRepository])], // or just Location entity [UserRepository,Location] if you didn't setup a custom LocationRepository
```

After that, inject it in your as what you did for  userRepo... service

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(LocationRepository)
    private locationRepository: LocationRepository,
    // or just  private locationRepository: Repository<Location>,
  ) {}
```

In the create method service get your locations:

```
 async  createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) { // usersSrvice
let locations = await this.locationRepository.findByIds(createUserDto.locations);
await this.userRepository.createMethodeName(createUserDto,locations) // add secand 
params for your locations
```

*don't hesitate to ask if you have any other questions*

Comment: thank you SO much! You are right, the two questions are related; I was hoping to help split questions to help others.