# Is it possible to auto insert records in table B when new record is created in Table A with sequelize typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have two tables `Job` and `Tags` table, I am using `sequelize` with `typescript` and `nestjs`.

Here are the `Job` and `Tags` models -

```
//Job.ts
@Table({ schema: "job", tableName: "job" })
export class Job extends Model<Job> {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  id: number;

  @Column
  title: string;

  // ... skipped other columns
}

//Tags.ts
@Table({ schema: "job", tableName: "job_tags" })
export class JobTags extends Model<JobTags> {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({ field: "job_id" })
  jobId: number;

  @Column
  tags: string;
}
```

My question is when we add any new `Job` record, is it possible to insert new record in `Tags` table, given that `tags` are available in `request body`?
Request body -

```
{
    "id": "20",
    "title": "Test Insert",
    "tags": ["TEST1", "TEST2"] // <= This should get inserted in Tags table with jobId as 20
}
```

Following entries should get created in `Tags` table.

```
job_id | tag
-------------
20    | TEST1
20    | TEST2
```

I have tried this using [Model association](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-association) but I was not sure if it does insert record when we define associations between tables and it did not worked out.

Comment: What type of a relationship are tags to a job? If the same tag can be used for different jobs, it could be a many-to-many.

Comment: Yes, its many-to-many, one job can have multiple tags and one tag can be associated with multiple jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779400/nestjs-typeorm-how-to-save-many-to-many) on saving a many-to-many relationship.

In short, you'll:

- pass an array of id's (tags) to your job entity.
- get each tag via `findByIds`
- save the job with the tags

In your `job.service` file you'll have something like this:

```
let tags = await this.tagsRepository.findByIds(
    createJobDto.tags,  // this is an array of id's
);

...

job.tags = tags;

...

job.save();
```

In the end, you'll end up with something that might look like this...

```
// tags.entity.ts

@ManyToMany((type) => Job, (job) => job.tags)
jobs: Job[];
```

```
// jobs.entity.ts

@ManyToMany((type) => Tag, (tag) => tag.jobs)
@JoinTable()
tags: Tag[];
```

Then in your `jobs.service.ts` file an example `create` method might look like:

```
// jobs.service.ts

create(createJobDto) {
    let tags = await this.tagsRepository.findByIds(
      createJobDto.tags,
    );

    return await this.jobsRepository.createJob(
      createJobDto,
      tags,
    );
}
```

Then your `jobs.repository.ts` might look something like this:

```
// jobs.repository.ts

createJob(createJobDto, tags) {
    const {name} = createJobDto;

    const job = this.create();

    job.name = name;
    job.tags = tags;

    ...
    
    try {
      await job.save();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(err);
    }

}
```

If you check your database, you should see a new table that will be called `jobs_tags` (or something like that). In that table you'll have columns for the `jobId` and the `tagId`.

Comment: So when we do `job.tags = tags` and `save` it, is it going to create entries in `tags` table? or it will insert tags in `Job` table only?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you a bit more insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't worked out for me. May be because our database does not have relationship between tables. It says missing foreign key for 'xyz' table.

Comment: Just for future users - I solved this by adding/deleting records with separate calls for other tables because it seems impossible to create this functionality without proper relationship. and we do not want our existing db to be altered.