# TypeORM How to UPDATE relations with multiple IDs in @ManyToMany?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885935/how-to-save-relation-in-manytomany-in-typeorm), read this [issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447) and the solution I found seems to be working fine when trying to insert a new record. however, I cannot update the relations of already existing records using the same approach, when I try to do so I'm getting the error ***[ExceptionsHandler] Cannot query across many-to-many for property genres***.

Here's a snippet of my code

```js
@Entity({ name: 'movies' })
export default class Movie extends Content {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Genre, (genre) => genre.movies, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  genres: Genre[];
}


@Entity({ name: 'genres' })
export default class Genre {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Movies, (movies) => movies.genres)
  movies: Movies[];
}
```

```js
// This method is working just fine!
async insert({ genres, ...others }: CreateMovieDto): Promise<Movie> {
  const record = this.moviesRepo.create(others);
  record.genres = genres.map((id) => ({ id } as Genre)); // this results an array like [{ id: 3 }]
  return await this.moviesRepo.save(record);
}

// This method is NOT working
// ERROR: [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot query across many-to-many for property genres
async update(id: number, { genres, ...others }: CreateMovieDto): Promise<Movie> {
  const record = this.moviesRepo.create(others);
  record.genres = genres.map((id) => ({ id } as Genre)); // this results an array like [{ id: 3 }]
  return await this.moviesRepo.update(id, record);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `Repository.save()` instead of `Repository.update()`. according to the [Repository API](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api/repository-api) documentation, you can use `.save()` to update records as well.

> If the entity already exist in the database, it is updated. If the
> entity does not exist in the database, it is inserted.

```js
async update(id: number, { genres, ...others }: CreateMovieDto): Promise<Movie> {
  const record = this.moviesRepo.create(others);
  record.genres = genres.map((id) => ({ id } as Genre));
  // don't forget add the id and make sure it's type of number
  record.id = id;
  // .update was changed to .save()
  return await this.moviesRepo.save(record);
}
```

P.S. Before updating the record please make sure it exists first. otherwise, a new record will be created.